# Object as a query parameter in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Is it possible to pass a javascript object as a "where query" in Firestore? The traditional way to do a query is like this:

```
this.db.collection('riders', ref => 
  ref.where('vehicle', '==', 'bicycle')
     .where('activity', '==', 'available')
     .where('isActive', '==', true)
 .valueChanges().subscribe();
```

But I would like to use an object like this:

```
query = {
   vehicle: 'bicycle',
   activity: 'available',
   isActive: true
}
```

I'm using AngularFire2

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
conditions = {
   vehicle: 'bicycle',
   activity: 'available',
   isActive: true
}
let query = ref;
Object.keys(conditions).forEach((key) => {
    query = query.where(key, "==", conditions[key]);
})

this.db.collection('riders', ref => query)
 .valueChanges().subscribe();
```

Comment: in the line:   let query = ref;

Comment: The ref here is whatever database reference you want to perform the query on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
query = {
   vehicle: 'bicycle',
   activity: 'available',
   isActive: true
}

this.db.list(`riders`, {
    query: {
    ...query
   }
});
```